# Conditional Rendering in Client-Side Component Triggers Hydration Error

Tags: next.js

I'm having problems with conditional rendering in my client components. Every time the conditional rendering (in this case based on the value of a cookie) is done, I get the following error:

```
react-dom.development.js:7076 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

I'm not sure if I use this wrong or have the wrong expectation. It seems obvious to me that the server rendered a different markup, as it's not necessarily aware of the state of the cookies. I thought this was the entire point of using client components.

Here's a minimal example to illustrate the problem:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import ClientComponent from "@/components/client-component";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="p-24">
      {/* <p>The current value of the cookie is: {currentVal?.value}</p> */}
      <form
        action={async function clearPrivilegeCookies() {
          "use server";
          const cookieStore = cookies();
          console.log("setting cookie to a");
          cookieStore.set("version", "a");
        }}
      >
        <button type="submit">Set version to "a"</button>
      </form>

      <form
        action={async function clearPrivilegeCookies() {
          "use server";
          const cookieStore = cookies();
          console.log("setting cookie to b");
          cookieStore.set("version", "b");
        }}
      >
        <button type="submit">Set version to "b"</button>
      </form>
      <ClientComponent />
    </main>
  );
}
```

And the client component is reading this cookie and printing the value

```
"use client";
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const version = getCookie("version");

  return (
    <p className="text-black">The cookies is currently set to: {version}</p>
  );
}
```

It works if I used a server component instead, but this is not what I need.

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default function ServerComponent() {
  console.log(`Render Server Component`);

  const cookiesStore = cookies();
  const version = cookiesStore.get("version");

  return (
    <p className="text-black">The cookies is currently set to: {version?.value}</p>
  );
}
```

The error occurs when you click either button (the UI updates immediately) **and refresh**. This will cause the hydration error. However, I'd assume that Next.js wouldn't flag this difference as an error.

[image: error screenshot]

I'm using the latest versions of the used deps

```
"dependencies": {
  "cookies-next": "^4.1.0",
  "next": "14.0.4",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use Server Component and exclude conditional rendering, but to capture the cookie version, you need to do something like this:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const ServerComponent = async () => {
  const cookieVersion = cookies().get("version");
  return (
    <p className="text-black">
      The cookie is currently set to: {cookieVersion?.value}
    </p>
  );
};

export default ServerComponent;
```

then you can use `<ServerComponent />` inside your `<Home/>` without hydration error.

2. In your provided context, I can't understand the reason you need the client component, but still, you can skip its rendering on server side until the component mounts on the client using useEffect, like this:

```
"use client";
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const version = getCookie("version");
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <p className="text-black">The cookies is currently set to: {version}</p>
  );
}
```

This will fix the hydration error also.