# NextJS hydration issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hydration

I have a NextJS app where I am getting this error:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <h1> in <h3>.
```

Even after looking at the error page, I am not clear what I am doing wrong.

app/page.tsx:

```
'use server'
import BtnClient from "@components/BtnClient"

const Home: React.FC = async () => {

  const logstate:number = 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>MAIN PAGE: SERVER RENDER</h1>

      <h3>{logstate==1 && <h1>LOGGED IN</h1>}</h3>
      <h3>{logstate==0 && <h1>LOGGED OUT</h1>}</h3>

      <BtnClient />

    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

BtnClient.tsx:

```
'use client';

const BtnClient = () => {

      function doit()
      {}

  return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={doit}> click </button>
      </div>
  );
}

export default BtnClient;
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. It seems you can't use server components in that way. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764381/conditional-rendering-in-client-side-component-triggers-hydration-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears too, if HTML is not valid.

```
<h3>{logstate==1 && <h1>LOGGED IN</h1>}</h3>
```

You must not nest `<h1>` inside `<h3>`

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Such a basic mistake, appreciated! That solves the problem